# AES encryption with user password as key c#

Tags: c#, encryption

Is there any way to encrypt/decrypt data with windows password or password hash as key?

Actually I want to personalize data for each user which other users can not access and the user him/herself does not know about this encrypt/decryption, I mean I don't want to ask user for a key but get a key that is not same for all users

If I generate a key for each user, I have to store it somewhere and other people can access to my generated key and access to all data, so I don't want to generate a key myself

I want to implement this scenario in C# and AES

Comment: If you don't care about the key and want to bind the encryption to the windows user, you can use the built-in Windows DPAPI methods: [ProtectedData.Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect) with `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser`

Comment: @kapsiR Yes this is what I want, thanks please add this as answer

Comment: Arsalan you need to edit question first si @kapsiR comment can be used as an answer. Right now it is just suggestion on what you could do but in no way *answers* the question. Generally it is better to ask "I want to do X and I tried Y" vs. "How to do Y".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about the key and want to bind the encryption to the windows user, you can use the built-in Windows DPAPI methods: [ProtectedData.Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect) with `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser`.

According to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/177686), DPAPI uses different encryption algorithms depending on the OS. (AES in case of Windows 10)

The code directly from the docs (slightly modified):

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Create a simple byte array containing data to be encrypted.
    byte [] secret = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    // Encrypt the data.
    byte [] encryptedSecret = Protect( secret );
}

public static byte [] Protect( byte [] data )
{
    // Encrypt the data using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser. The result can be decrypted
    // only by the same current user.
    return ProtectedData.Protect( data, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser );
}
```

Beware that if you loose access to your Windows account, you can't decrypt the encrypted data anymore!

> Windows Vaults stored in the profile of a user are protected by the Windows Data Protection application programming interface (DPAPI). **This protection depends on the Security ID (SID) of the user. The SID for the user is unique to the computer on which the user account is created.** As a result, simply restoring a previously backed up Vault on a different computer is not sufficient. The DPAPI keys on the new computer also need to be updated so that they can decrypt the restored Vault.

Additionally it is recommended to use the additional entropy to strengthen the encryption.